# How to make Gradle cache persistent through Docker containers?

Tags: java, docker, gradle, dockerfile, gradle-dependencies

I have a Java(Gradle) project. A docker image is built in CI using Dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:6.8.3-jdk11
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/app
WORKDIR /home/gradle/app
RUN gradle compileTestJava
```

Although `gradle compileTestJava` downloads all dependencies, when the container is run from the image, gradle cache turns out to be empty and all dependencies are being redownloaded.

How can I make gradle cache attached to the image so it would be used in containers?

Comment: Can you show your `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: @Max added to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that `.gradle` folder is set as a `VOLUME` in `gradle:6.8.3-jdk11` which prevents cache from being saved in the image.

The solution was to create a custom base gradle image without a volume.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle caches artifacts in USER_HOME/.gradle folder.
For this either you have to use `Bind mounts` or `Volumes` and attach your containers `$USER_HOME/.gradle` path to that volume.

For volumes,

```
docker volume create <your_volume_name>
```

And when running your container attach the volume like this

```
docker run -v <your_volume_name>:USER_HOME/.gradle yourImage:tag
```

or When you use a bind mount, a file or directory on the host machine is mounted into a container.

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=<your_host_path>,target=/USER_HOME/.gradle yourImage:tag
```